# Change p-column width

Tags: css, width, primeng

I'm in a project where I need to use PrimeNG to do tables and I have a problem with defining the width of the first column.

In my HTML code, I have something like:

```
<p-datatable styleClass="myTable">
     <p-column>

     </p-column>
     ...
</p-datable>
```

And in my CSS, I have something like:

```
.myTable td:nth-child(1) {
    width:300px;
}
```

Also, I've tried with the following HTML:

```
 <p-datatable>
     <p-column styleClass="col1">

     </p-column>
     ...
 </p-datable>
```

And in my CSS:

```
td.col1 {
    width: 300px;
}
```

And I also did inspect the code and saw the class of the row which is `tr.ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even` and tried the following CSS:

```
tr.ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 500px !important;
}
```

And nothing seems to work.

Can someone tell me if it's possible to define the width of the column and, if so, how can I do that?

Comment: More reading on overriding angular css: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-component-styles-host-host-context-deep-selector-example

Answer (score 23):

You can define the width manually, try this:

```
<p-column [style]="{'width':'300px'}" </p-column>
```

Comment: still can't quite believe this is the best solution :-/

Comment: note: `width` doesn't actually need to be in quotes, but if you're trying to center text then `text-align` must be in quotes `[style]="{width: '180px', 'text-align': 'center'}"`

Comment: This doesn't work well with `[responsive]="true"`. See also http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=48355&hilit=column+width

Comment: how to set width for dynamic columns based on column header name

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with angular, you can update css file to change PrimeNg styling with following sample code,

```
:host /deep/ .ui-datatable{
    width: 500px;
}
```

For information on Shadow DOM, please refer https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html